# Firestore order by query with multiple where clause

Tags: swift, google-cloud-firestore

I'm looking to do this query where I order by `geohash` field while at the same time having a `whereField` clause on 2 separate fields, namely `endDate` and `status`. Is there any way to overcome this limitation? Code below is the query.

```
Firestore.firestore()
    .collection("collection-id")
    .order(by: "geohash")
    .whereField("endDate", isGreaterThan: Timestamp(date: .now))
    .whereField("status", isEqualTo: "Active")
    .getDocuments(source: .server) { querySnapshot, error in
        guard let querySnapshot else {
            print("Error: \(error)") // It'll always hit this error
            return
        }
    }
```

Here is the error output when trying to get documents:

> Error Domain=FIRFirestoreErrorDomain
> Code=3 "inequality filter property and first sort order must be the same: endDate and geohash" 
> UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=inequality filter property and first sort order must be the same: end_datetime and geohash

Additional notes: A **composite index** for this query is already enabled when I'm running this query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Queries with multiple relational clauses (like the one you shared) need a [composite index](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/index-overview) in order to function, which you'll need to create explicitly yourself.

If no such index exists, your code should be raising an error that includes a link that makes it easy to create the index. If not, you can also build it manually in the Firestore console.

For all on this, see https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/indexing

---

The error message you added is quite specific and has been covered multiple times before, so I recommend [searching for it](https://www.google.com/search?q=firestore+inequality+filter+property+and+first+sort+order+must+be+the+same).

The short of it is that you'll have to `.orderBy("endDate")` before ordering by anything else. That also means that the results will first be ordered on `endDate` and only ordered on `geohash` for documents with the same end date.

There is no way to change that behavior, so if you need the results ordered by end data, you will have to reorder them in your application code.

Comment: Hi Frank, said composite index already exists and enabled when I'm running the query. I've edited the question and attached the error I'm faced with. Please do review it if you have the time.

Comment: That error message is quite specific, and has been covered multiple times before, so I recommend searching for it. The short of it is that you'll have to `.orderBy("endDate")` before ordering by anything else. That also means that the results will first be ordered on `endDate` and only ordered on `geohash` for documents with the same end date. There is no way to change that behavior, so if you need the results ordered by end data, you will have to reorder them in your appllication code.